# Can't return a xlsx file from a Node.js (express) service which gets it from a S3 bucket, for use by a browser app

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Created a xlsx file in Excel, uploaded from desktop manually to AWS S3 via console.
Now want to add an endpoint to a Node.js express service that will retrieve that file from S3 and pass it back to a javascript browser application.

Seems fine with plain text file, but keep getting HTTP status code 500 for the xlsx file (and even csv created in Excel).

tried variations like:

```js
res.send(s3.getObject().toString()); //this works with plain text file
```

```js
res.send(s3.getObject().toString('utf-8'));
```

```js
res.send(s3.getObject().toString('binary'));
```

no luck with any of these, call fails immediately with 500 Internal Server error.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```js
    s3.headObject(params, 
        (err, data)=>{
            if (err) {
                  return res.status(500).end(err.message);
            }
            // Add the content type to the response (it's not propagated from the S3 SDK)
            res.set({
                'Content-Type': data.ContentType,
                'Content-Length': data.ContentLength,
                'Last-Modified': data.LastModified,
                'ETag': data.ETag
            });
            s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res)
        }
    );
```